# Error al instalar eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide

Hola quiero instalar el eclipse pero a mitad de la instalación me da un error ,tengo instalado el Java Development Kit 17 no c q pueda ser [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el error que te manda.

Answer (score 1):

Comprueba que este el path del jdk en las variables de entorno de forma correcta, de no ser así añade la ruta correspondiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]